# Integration question with square root and cubic function

Tags: calculus, integration

I am faced with this question. I tried u-substitution and integration by parts but was not successful. A hint may also suffice.  Thanks

$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{3x^3-x^2+2x-4}{\sqrt{x^2-3x+2}}dx$

I took out x-1 common from both the numerator and denominator only to find myself stuck further than I anticipated.

Substituting the radical as u , that is 
$u=\sqrt{x^2-3x+2}$

doesn't help either as then i cannot express the numerator in terms of u

Comment: have a cup of coffee and try again

Comment: $$x^2-3x+2=\dfrac{(2x-3)^2-1}4$$  Set $2x-3=\sec t$